# UIImageView screenshot clipping with subviews

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to screenshot a UIImageView which has alpha (love heart with alpha transparency for the heart, black edges) which is moveable, scalable and rotatable - on top of a UIImageView which doesn't move.

What I'm trying to accomplish is allowing the user to move the heart shape on top (already got the code working for that) - then when they click a next button, it will take a screenshot of the heart shape and also capture the image underneath. I have this code passing through the screenshotted image to a segue. This is what I have so far and this is the result.

Here is my current code and the before/afters:

`moveableMaskImageView` is the Heart UIImageView
`outletPreview` is the UIImageView underneath

```
#pragma screenshotImage:
- (UIImage *)screenShotImage {
CGRect rect = [moveableMaskImageView frame];
NSLog(@"Screenshot X: %f Screenshot Y: %f Screenshot W: %f Screenshot H: %f",rect.origin.x,rect.origin.y,rect.size.width,rect.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[outletPreview.layer renderInContext:context];
[moveableMaskImageView.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return capturedImage;
}
```

**Before (Positioning):**

[image: Before]

**After:**

[image: After]

Comment: What exactly should we help you out with? Can you please explicitly state what is the problem?

Comment: I'm trying to make the result image the frame and translation of the heart image - so everything outside the heart image would be cut out, leaving the heart and the clipped subview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question - I hope this helps anyone out because it baffled me for a while:

Instead of using my screenshot function to clip the image - I used this piece of code that I found laying around on the internet:

```
- (UIImage*)imageByCropping:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(outletContainer.frame.size);/// use your screen or photo frame
[outletContainer.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([screenshot CGImage], rect);
UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

/*    no origin .....
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tempview.frame.size);
 [[self.photo layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
 cropped= UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 */
return cropped;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is you see a quarter of what is selected.

try replacing

this

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0.0f);
```

with this

```
CGSize *size = CGSizeMake(rect.size.x *2, rect.size.y *2);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0f);
```